# Get the Effective Price base on Date in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a problem getting the right "Price" for a product based on Effectivity date. I've checked on StackOverFlow but on Google Sheet is not mentioned
I need a table of `Effective Price table` after querying `Price change history table`
Please help me solve this problem
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Please share a link to your spreadsheet, or to a copy of it. The volunteer contributors here will need to see your full layout, ranges, data, data types, international locale and more in order to create an effective solution; and we cannot get that from an image alone.

Comment: Thank Erik, I'll remember this.

Comment: If you would still like to share a link to your spreadsheet or a copy of it, others may be willing to share additional solutions with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try for chosen codes

```
=query(A:C,"select B,C where A='"&E3&"' and C<=DATE'"&TEXT($E$1,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' order by C desc limit 1",0)
```

[image]

### other solution, by one formula for all codes at once

```
=arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(unique(A2:A),query(A2:C,"select A,B,C where C<=DATE'"&TEXT($E$1,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' order by C desc ",0),{1,2,3},0)))
```

[image]

### for all codes at once, including those that are out of bounds

```
=sort(arrayformula(iferror(vlookup(unique(A2:A),
{query(A2:C,"select A,B,C where C<=DATE'"&TEXT($D$1,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' order by C desc ",0);
query(A2:C,"select A,' ','-' where A is not null ",0)},
{1,2,3},0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank Mike, this code is very useful but we need to add new Code of foods in column E if we have new ones on table

Comment: You can add in E3 `=unique(A2:A)` then drag below the formula proposed in F3

Comment: Thank Mike very much, Have a good day! :)

Comment: Hi Mike, I think the code ``` order by Col1 desc limit "&counta(unique(A2:A)``` has problem and I can not get the right output

Comment: Yes, it depends on your data when not all items have the same dates. I thought about it and didn't get a solution. Except the first, by adding in E3 `=unique(A2:A)` then dragging below the formula proposed in F3

Comment: Hi Mike, I think the code ``` order by Col1 desc limit "&counta(unique(A2:A)``` has problem and I can not get the right output. I add new material named `Bean and Unit price 1,2,3 according to price change at 1-Jan, 1-Feb, 1-Mar and let Input Date = 8-Apr. I got Meat - Fish-Meat (must be BEAN)

Comment: OK, I think I got an new exercise about subquery because of your instruction :)

Answer (score 0):

***Formula in E3***

```
=QUERY(A:C,"select A,max(C) where C <= date '"&TEXT(E1,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and A is not null group by A label A '',max(C) ''",1)
```

***Formula in G3***

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(E3:E&F3:F,{A:A&C:C,B:B},2,FALSE))
```

[image]

If you want to have the same sequence of columns as yours, you need 3 formulas.

Comment: Thank idfurw, can we add column B ```Price```on ```Select...``` statement in stead of adding ArrayFormula at G3?

Comment: No, I don't think you can.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll study ArrayFormula indeed :)